# Issue with speedometer highcharts dynamically update guage range

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a use case where I need to modify the Guage range dynamically, but when I do this my highcharts graph behaves weirdly and the range goes out of bounds. Please look at the image below[image: Speedometer Highchart]

This happens only after the `7th iteration (value is 0.007)`. You can find my code on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/S6LtL/

[My Highcharts Speedometer Code (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/S6LtL/)

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration, you are adding a new plotBand, but not removing the old ones:

```
chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('red');
chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('green');                
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
    id: 'red',
    from: newVal - 0.005,
    to: newVal - 0.001,
    color: '#DF5353' // red
});
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
    id: 'green',
    from: newVal - 0.001,
    to: newVal + 0.005,
    color: '#55BF3B' //green
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6LtL/1/).

Comment: @Mark...Thanks for tha answer, it solved my issue. but how do I fix the range zooming in effect whenever I update the plotBand.

Comment: @skokal01, what do you mean by "range zooming in effect"?  The "Blinking" of the plotbands?

Comment: @Mark...yes I meant Blinking of the plotbands.